# Access to the private list

Tags: java

I have the following class with the following methods and with the following `LinkedList`:

```
public class Class1 {
    private LinkedList<Integer> list;

    Class1() {
        list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
    public void add(int num){
       list.add(num);
    }

    public static void main() {
        Class1 obj = new Class1();
        //what should i do to add integers to the private list
        obj.add(...);
        mean(obj)???
    }
}
```

How is it possible to access the private list? How can I print the list? I want to calculate the average and the variance of the list? How can I have access to the private list?

Comment: :) off course this is not my desire. I want to have it private.

Comment: Why? You want to have **public access** to the list. What makes you want it to be private?

Comment: In `Class1`? You can use `obj.list` in `main` (the access level is `private`, but you only appear to have one `class`).

Comment: Only if I turn the llist to public can I have access to list with obj.llist

Comment: @JoseRamon No. `Class1` can access its' own `private` methods and fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a getter method to get the values:

```
public LinkedList<Integer> getList(){
     return this.list;
}
```

and you can access the value by obj.getList()

or just click ctrl+alt+s+r (eclipse generate them automatically)

Answer (score 2):

```
Encapsulation is one of the four fundamental OOP concepts. The other three are inheritance, polymorphism, and abstraction.
```

and simple reference link : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm

create getter and setter

```
private LinkedList<Integer> list;

    public LinkedList<Integer> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(LinkedList<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
```

Comment: Surely you break encapsulation by adding a public getter that allows the original copy of your list to be modified at will by *any other class*?

Comment: @AndrewRegan also true, the main purpose of encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

Add public methods to class1 to interact and extract the information you want  from the Arraylist. Example methods add(int num) getAverage()

Then Class1 myClass =  new Class1 (); myClass.add(1);

Comment: Yah I have add the method add. In main function I create my object obj and with obj.add() I add numbers. But how can I print them then/?

Comment: For example if I create a function for the average mean and I want to have as an argument a ist. What should I add in the call of the mean function in the main, mean(obj)???

Comment: Well 2 ways you can have that function inside the Class1 so you just call obj.print()..you could use system.Out.println within that method. Or you could return the list then print it from your main method

Comment: There would be no argument for the method obj.averageMean() the method would work with the private list within the class, then return an integer

Comment: I think you many need to look into oop and methods within Java a bit more.